# Does Oracle's (DB query) fuzzy match (for auto-completion) use a map-reduce in its implementation?

Tags: oracle, indexing, oracle11g, pattern-matching, fuzzy-search

The context is that we're building a website, with an 'autocomplete' function for the names of contacts in the site. The website calls out to an [Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/database/index.html) database with the partial names entered and gives the top 10 matching results, which are then animated on the screen in real time.

To my understanding this is implemented as a [pattern match](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions007.htm) (`LIKE %name%`) against a table of names with an index on the column. Some people call this a [fuzzy search](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/text.112/e24436/cqoper.htm) (`CONTAINS`). (The implementation is proprietary from a vendor)

I recently heard a friend make the claim:

> Oracles fuzzy match use a map-reduce in its implementation, because it has to split the job up across workers and bring it back together again.

I called him out on this - and pointed out it was probably a traversal of an index implemented in a tree structure.

My question is: **Does Oracle's (DB query) fuzzy match (for auto-completion) use a map-reduce in its implementation?**

Comment: Parallel databases have been "split[ting] jobs up across workers and bringing [the results] back together again" for over two decades.  Map-reduce has existed since the 1960s when it was implemented in programming languages such as Lisp (*parallel* map-reduce is more recent).  Oracle may be using parallel map-reduce, but the statement is non-sense.

Comment: I'm afraid that whoat you wrote in complete nonsense. Oracle does not run queries in parallel, unless instructed. And usually you do NOT want the whole capacity of DB hardware to be assigned to a single user.

Comment: Oracle can use index(tree search) for a search pattern which does not start with a wildcard. If you want to use pattern matching for `like '%name%'` you have to use some advanced techniques.